# ASP.NET Data Protection - Migrating From MachineKey

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, encryption

I was using `MachineKey.Protect` and `MachineKey.Unprotect` in ASP.NET for encrypting and decrypting sensitive data. Now, I am trying to migrate to ASP.NET Core. I read that it has a data protection API for this. But I have the following questions for which I could not find answers in the documents:

1. I was defining the validation key and the decryption key in web.config. But the data protection api seems to generate keys automatically. So, how do I manually assign these same pair of keys so that previously encrypted data can be decrypted.
2. Data protection api seems to automatically expire keys and create new ones. So, how is it able to decrypt data encrypted with a previous key? Should I somehow disable this expiration mechanism?

Answer (score -1):

You can use these codes for Machine Key protection in .net core .
See this link too . [AspNetTicketBridge](https://github.com/dmarlow/AspNetTicketBridge)

```
public async Task InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {
            var authorizationToken = context.Request.Headers.FirstOrDefault(q => q.Key.Equals("Authorization")).Value;

            // Decrypt the token
            var ticket = MachineKeyTicketUnprotector.UnprotectOAuthToken(GetTokenWithoutBearer(authorizationToken), _config.DecryptionKey, _config.ValidationKey);

            // The ticket is in v3 format and needs to be converted to v5 (ASP.NET Core 2.0).
            // Can use whatever you want for AuthScheme
            var newTicket = AuthenticationTicketConverter.Convert(ticket, "");

            // If using a custom AuthenticationHandler, you can return the new ticket 
            // in the HandleAuthenticateAsync method.
            var result = AuthenticateResult.Success(newTicket);

            if (!result.Succeeded)
                await UnAuthorizeRequest(context);

            await _next.Invoke(context);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            await UnAuthorizeRequest(context);
        }
    }`
```